# Does aria2c upload my data?

Tags: aria2

I have a question regarding a sentence from the manpage of aria2c:

> It supports downloading a file from HTTP(S)/FTP /SFTP and BitTorrent at the same time, while the data downloaded from HTTP(S)/FTP/SFTP is uploaded to the BitTorrent swarm.

That sounds odd, does this mean if I use aria2 to download large files from my company's FTP server, that data gets send out to BitTorrent for everyone to pull potentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if you download something from FTP only, nothing will be uploaded. 
Just if you use BitTorrent to download a file, and you download the same file via HTTP(S)/FTP/SFTP, then aria2 is smart enough to add the file parts from HTTP(S)/FTP/SFTP to the BitTorrent parts. And as BitTorrent downloads always are shared (uploaded) as long as the download process is running, these parts from other sources are uploaded as well, just as if you downloaded them with BitTorrent protocol only.